# Making a post request in a for loop in python using face++ API

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests, export-to-csv, api-key

i need some help with my code here. I am new in using APIs and i have a file containing 100000 photos that i want to detect and analyse. Until now with the code i have written i can only detect one image, but when i try to test for more then it doesn't let me do the detection. In face++ free APIKEY you can only make 1 request per second so thats why i have the time.sleep(). Moreover, if i test the code in more than one images, lets say 2-3 images then it saves only the first image's result in the csv. Can you help me solve this ?

```
import requests

for i in range(1,100000):
    http_url="https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect"
    path='..'
    key=".."
    secret=".."
    data={ "api_key": "..","api_secret":".."}
    files= {"image_file": open(path+str(i) +".jpg", 'rb')}
    response=requests.post(http_url,data=data,files=files)
    time.sleep(2)
    req_con=response.content.decode('utf-8')
    req_dict=JSONDecoder().decode(req_con)
    time.sleep(2)
    file = open("out.csv", "wb")
    file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write to csv as append mode 
    `file = open("out.csv", "ab")`
you are overwriting the same line again.